# result should have been changed by 1, but wasn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm having trouble getting this pass, although things work in both the console and the browser.  Thanks for your help!

Here's my spec:

```
  before(:each) do
    @attr = {name: "Example Class"}
    @create = post :create, {user_id: @user.id, student_group: @attr}
  end

  it "should create a user" do  
    lambda do
      @create
    end.should change {@user.student_groups.count}.by(1)
  end
```

And my `new` and `create` actions in the controller:

```
def new
  @student_group  = @user.student_groups.new
  @title = "Create a new class"
end

...

def create
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.create(params[:student_group])
  if @student_group.save
    # for now redirect to 
  redirect_to classes_path, flash: { success: "#{@student_group.name} created! Next, add some students" }
    # redirect_to new_student_group_student_path
  else
    @title = "Create a new class"
    flash.now[:error] = "Something's gone wrong.  Please try again!"
    render 'new' 
  end  
end
```

and the error:

```
1) StudentGroupsController POST 'create' success should create a user
 Failure/Error: lambda do
   result should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/student_groups_controller_spec.rb:113:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda does not contain executable code, I think the moving creation code to this lambda will resolve the issue.

```
it "should create a user" do  
  lambda do
    post :create, {user_id: @user.id, student_group: @attr}
  end.should change {@user.student_groups.count}.by(1)
end
```

Comment: hmm, yeah it worked, thanks!  why can the lambda not read `@create`?

Comment: lambda is object with executable code (usually); @create is just variable, it doesn't make any action.